# fputcsv causing "Headers Already Sent" error

Tags: php, magento, csv, export, fputcsv

I am writing a PHP export script for my copy of magento. For some reason, the following code gives me a "Headers already sent" error:

```
//Load magento and set to match frontend
require_once '../../app/Mage.php';
umask(0);
Mage::app();
Mage::app()->loadArea(Mage_Core_Model_App_Area::AREA_FRONTEND);

//Send headers to browser to prep for csv file download
header('Content-Type: text/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=exportSKUs.csv');


//Load only product collection details that we need.
$product    = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
$product->getCollection()->getSelect()->limit(5);
$products   = $product->getCollection()
    ->addFieldToFilter('status','1')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('sku')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('upc')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('status')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('price')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('special_price')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('description')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('category_ids')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('short_description');

//Open current output to fputcsv
$fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');

//CSV headers
$headerRow = array(
    'name',
    'sku',
    'upc',
    'status',
    'price',
    'special_price',
    'description',
    'category_ids',
    'short_description'
);
fputcsv($fp, $headerRow);
$count = 0;
//CSV Rows
foreach($products as &$product){
    $categoryIds = implode(',', $product->getCategoryIds());
    $row = array(
        $product->getName(),
        $product->getSku(),
        $product->getUpc(),
        $product->getStatus(),
        $product->getPrice(),
        $product->getSpecialPrice(),
        $product->getDescription(),
        $categoryIds,
        $product->getShortDescription()
    );
    fputcsv($fp, $row);
    $count++;
    if($count>5){
        //Close current output (save csv)
        fclose($fp);
        exit;
    }
}
```

The line of code here that is causing me problems is this: `fputcsv($fp, $headerRow);`
For some reason, when this line is commented out the script runs fine. However, when this line is run with the script, it shoots the header already sent error. I don't understand why I am able to run fputcsv INSIDE my foreach loop any number of times (`fputcsv($fp, $row);`)but I can not run it before the foreach loop at all.

I have ways around this issue, so it's not super critical, but I really wish I could understand what was going on here to cause this.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have change your code ... check this.I have using magento process to export...

```
<?php
//Load magento and set to match frontend
require_once '../../app/Mage.php';
umask(0);
Mage::app();
Mage::app()->loadArea(Mage_Core_Model_App_Area::AREA_FRONTEND);

//Send headers to browser to prep for csv file download
//header('Content-Type: text/csv');
//header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=exportSKUs.csv');
//
$filename="exportSKUs.csv";


//Load only product collection details that we need.
$product    = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
$product->getCollection()->getSelect()->limit(5);
$products   = $product->getCollection()
    ->addFieldToFilter('status','1')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('sku')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('upc')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('status')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('price')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('special_price')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('description')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('category_ids')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('short_description');


 $io = new Varien_Io_File();
                $path = Mage::getBaseDir('var') . DS . 'export' . DS;
                $name = md5(microtime());
                $file = $path . DS . $name . '.csv';
                $io->setAllowCreateFolders(true);
                $io->open(array('path' => $path));
                $io->streamOpen($filename, 'w+');
                $io->streamLock(true);
                $headerRow = array(
                    'name',
                    'sku',
                    'upc',
                    'status',
                    'price',
                    'special_price',
                    'description',
                    'category_ids',
                    'short_description'
                );
                $io->streamWriteCsv($headerRow);

                    foreach($products as &$product){
                    $categoryIds = implode(',', $product->getCategoryIds());
                    $row = array(
                    $product->getName(),
                    $product->getSku(),
                    $product->getUpc(),
                    $product->getStatus(),
                    $product->getPrice(),
                    $product->getSpecialPrice(),
                    $product->getDescription(),
                    $categoryIds,
                    $product->getShortDescription()
                    );
                    $io->streamWriteCsv($row);
                }
?>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for writing this version of it! I should be using Varien_Io_File, but I had not heard of it before. That being said, I really wish I knew what was going wrong with my script that I posted. I have a working version of this code, but I wanted to understand where it was failing.

Comment: The only fputcsv that is causing the header already sent error is the fputcsv for the header column in my code. The fputcsv WITHIN the foreach loop does not give me the header already sent error. For this reason, I do not believe mage.php is sending headers before my file- or the foreach would give me the error as well. Any thoughts?